# Specialization for a constant function argument

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to define a function `void f(int i)` that would only compile and do something when called as `f(1)` and would cause a compile error in all other cases. Is it possible to do with a template specialization?

Comment: yes, it's possible; but if you pass the number as template argument; calling `f()` as `f<1>()` or `f(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{})` or something similar.

Comment: Struggling with the use case.  If the function has only one valid parameter and it is known at compile time then why have it as an argument at all?  void f(){ int i = 1;...}

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble and use `if (i == 1)`.

Comment: I would like to declare a syntax `void set(int option, int value)` `int get(int option)`. There's a lot of possible options available but currently I only need to implement it for one option. Hence, I want to declare a single 'int value' member to store it instead of 'int[] values', and the specialization would directly access that member for efficiency reasons. And I would like to use the syntax with a function parameter instead of a template argument in case I want to switch to an implementation that actually uses different options, and then I wouldn't need to change the calling syntax.

Comment: If the number of options is not too large, you can use an `enum` as an argument.

Comment: Why not use a parameter class?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment that you would prefer not to use a template, and from the requirements you mentioned there, an option might be using an `enum` as argument, which means you limit the input to a given set of arguments:

```
enum argument{option1,option2,option3};

void f(argument x){
  // do stuff
}
```

(the example is using three allowed values, but you can use any number of possible values)

While not being exactly what you asked for (the signature of `f` changed), it basically serves the same purpose.

You can now call `f` with either `option1`, `option2` or `option3` as input (or any other ones you specify in `argument`). As `enum` is implicitly convertible to `int`, you can use it as such in the function body, and specify the possible values also directly in `argument`

```
enum argument{option1=20,option2=23,option3=12};
```

Note that even though `arguments` can be implicitly converted to `int`, it does not  work the other way around, so you will not be able to call `f` directly on `int` inputs, which is why it is not quite exactly what you asked for.

Note that while you can use `static_cast` to convert `int` to `argument`, it is dangerous, because this will again compile for any input, and might even invoke UB depending on the value you cast.